# Undefined Reference When Implementing Static Method Outside Of Header File

Tags: c++

I have a class `A` which has a static instance member `A* a`.
I am trying to create a static method `initA()` which initiates `a`.
However, if I implement the method in a `cpp` file instead of the header file, I get an undefined reference error:

The code for the header file:

```
class A
{
public:
  static A *a;
  static void initA ();
};
```

The code for the `cpp` file:

```
#include "A.h"
void A::initA(){
    A::a = new A();
}
```

Compiling this code yields the following error (copied from an online IDE. My VS yields different error but its meaning is the same):

```
/var/tmp/ccW1EJl7.o: In function `A::initA()':
A.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `A::a'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note that replacing the line `A::a = new A();` with `a = new A();` (omitting the `A::`) yields the same error.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong and how can I implement the method correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/560648 (& your book should explain this)

Comment: Also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/145299/17853

Comment: @Peter Incorrect. `initA` was linked, and that module generated the error that `A::a` was not defined (because it wasn't)

Comment: My question is why wasn't `A::a` undefined? It is defined in the header file.

Comment: @GuyYafe  No, it isn't; that's just a declaration. Please read the linked resources.

Comment: It's not. It's declared in the header.